# How to use SomeTable.create and perform join together in the same query

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose-schema

My question is that I have a static method in my mongoose Schema  like this

```
const chatMessageSchema = new Schema({
  id: String,
  something: String,
  .
  .
  posted_by_user: String,
}, { collection: 'XXXX' });
```

And in one of the static methods of chatMessageSchema

```
chatMessageSchema.statics.createATextPostInChatRoom = function (roomid, 
message) {
  return this.create({
    roomid: roomid,
    message: message,
    type: MESSAGE_TYPES.TYPE_TEXT,
    notes: {},
    posted_by_user: 'XXXXXXX',
    read_by_recipients: posted_by_user
 })
 .then(post => post)
 .catch(error => {
   throw(error)
  });
}
```

Now what I wanted to do is

During create I want to perform a join on `posted_by_user: 'XXXX'` Or will I have to do this join in the next `.then()` block

Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: I think you actually mean `.findOne()` on the `User` model in a "mongoose hook" or something like that. `$lookup` is an aggregation pipeline operator used to perform *"a type of left join"* between two collections. Your statement here sounds more like *"looking up the user"* that what the pipeline operator actually does.

Comment: Yeah I actually want to lookup the user but I want to do this in same query when I create an entry in my db.

Comment: That's what I am trying to clear up. You have written `$lookup` all over your question, but it's clear that you actually want something else and misunderstood what the operator is actually for. You should remove all those references from your question because it looks kind of silly and is very misleading to what you actually need to get done.

Comment: Umm. Without using the words "lookup" or "join" do you think you might have a try at explaining to me exactly what you expect to happen when you call create. Because you seem really confused about this to me.

Comment: Oh okay, so what I want to happen is that when I create post I also provide it userId who created that post. Now based on the userId I am providing in this.create() I want to get information from the userId which is in another table.

Comment: But why? What are you going to do with said information when you get it?
 Please expand.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146863/discussion-between-adeel-imran-and-neil-lunn).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it using MongoDB `$lookup` method which I used in an `aggregation`.